# most efficient Entity Framework Code First method of flattening / projecting parent entity with specific child

Tags: linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have a parent entity `Widget` with core members and multiple `WidgetTranslation` children that have language translated members i.e. `Description` text available in English, French, German etc.

e.g.

```
public class Widget
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<WidgetTranslation> WidgetTranslations { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetTranslation
{
  public int WidgetId { get; set; } 
  public virtual Widget Widget { get; set; }

  public int LanguageId { get; set; }
  public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

What is the most efficient method of querying the widget collection, flattening for a given `LanguageId` & projecting to a `TranslatedWidget` DTO

```
public class TranslatedWidget
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public int LanguageId { get; set; }
  public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

Given `languageId` I've started with

```
DbSet.Select(w => new TranslatedWidget
  {
    Id = w.Id,
    Code = w.Code,
    LanguageId = w.LanguageId,
    Name = w.WidgetTranslations.First(wt=>wt.LanguageId == languageId).Name,
    Description = w.WidgetTranslations.First(wt=>wt.LanguageId == languageId).Description,
    Summary = w.WidgetTranslations.First(wt=>wt.LanguageId == languageId).Summary
  });
```

But I've a feeling this is inefficient and won't scale for more properties on `WidgetTranslation`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SelectMany to flatten structures via a single join:

```
var widgetQuery = from w in dbSet.Widgets
                  from wt in w.WidgetTranslations
                  where wt.Language == languageId
                  select new TranslatedWidget
                  {
                     Id = w.Id,
                     Code = w.Code,
                     LanguageId = w.LanguageId,
                     Name = wt.Name,
                     Description = wt.Description,
                     Summary = wt.Summary
                  });
```

I'm assuming here that you only have a single translation for each widget in a given language.

Comment: Thanks. It's rare that I see an answerer voting up someone else's answer.

Comment: Thanks Jim, the resulting EF SQL generated is much cleaner.

Comment: @JimWooley you mentioned to use SelectMany but your example works with just the Select - am I missing something?

Comment: Under the covers the `from ... from` syntax is translated into `.SelectMany`.

Answer (score 0):

I would move `Name`, `Description` and `Summary` into a nested class of your DTO...

```
public class TranslatedWidgetTranslation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}

public class TranslatedWidget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public TranslatedWidgetTranslation Translation { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can project into that class and need `First` only once which would result in only one `TOP(1)` subquery in SQL instead of three:

```
DbSet.Select(w => new TranslatedWidget
{
    Id = w.Id,
    Code = w.Code,
    LanguageId = languageId,
    Translation = w.WidgetTranslations
        .Where(wt => wt.LanguageId == languageId)
        .Select(wt => new TranslatedWidgetTranslation
        {
            Name = wt.Name,
            Description = wt.Description,
            Summary = wt.Summary
        })
        .FirstOrDefault()
});
```

You must use `FirstOrDefault` here, `First` is not supported in a LINQ-to-Entities projection.

If you don't want that nested type you can project into anonymous types first and then convert into your final class, but the code will be a bit longer:

```
DbSet.Select(w => new
{
    Id = w.Id,
    Code = w.Code,
    LanguageId = languageId,
    Translation = w.WidgetTranslations
        .Where(wt => wt.LanguageId == languageId)
        .Select(wt => new
        {
            Name = wt.Name,
            Description = wt.Description,
            Summary = wt.Summary
        })
        .FirstOrDefault()
})
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => new TranslatedWidget
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Code = x.Code,
    LanguageId = x.LanguageId,
    Name = x.Translation != null ? x.Translation.Name : null,
    Description = x.Translation != null ? x.Translation.Description : null,
    Summary = x.Translation != null ? x.Translation.Summary : null
});
```